# Unable to access files on Ubuntu which is of Windows directory

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I want to access files that is on Windows since my laptop is dual booted. And I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 platform. But the problem is I'm unable to access my files. Following is the dialog box message appearing:

Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/iammnz/90502B6A502B566E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/iammnz/90502B6A502B566E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Answer (score 0):

You should login to windows and restart. Then login to your Ubuntu to access that partition of yours. To make it short, always you should `restart` your windows and then login to Ubuntu.

It's one of Windows features to improve boot up time and only works when Windows is shut down.